# Code Igniter - print $Controller->session without knowing the key?

Tags: session, codeigniter

Instead of doing the following:

```
print $this->session->userdata('username');
print $this->session->userdata('email');
print $this->session->userdata('phone');
print $this->session->userdata('fax');
//etc...
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
foreach($this->session as $key=>$val) print $key.'-'.$val;
```

Or is it possible to do something like

```
print_r($this->session);
```

The reason I'm asking is because I don't know what the SESSION keys are and I also want to be able to loop through CI Session values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->session` is an object of course,and you can dump it using `print_r` or `var_dump`

but i recommend using this for fetching all of your session data except for flash data:


`$sessionArray = $this->session->all_userdata();`

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
print_r($this->session);
```

It will return an array of all your sessions.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked by casting `$this->session` as and array then dumping it.

```
        $this->load->library('session'); #load session
        foreach ((array)$this->session as $sess_arr_k => $sess_arr_v)
        {
          "<li>". $sess_arr_k .":<br />". var_dump($arrSessElement) ."</li>";
        }
```

Worked for me.

Comment: OP said that he "also want to be able to loop through CI Session values."

Comment: Since at this point it's an array it should be easier to loop through (even recursively), though I believe he needs to know what is there available to him. Anyway, it is just another way to do this.

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't use casting much, an example of it being looped would be clarifying. Appreciate it.